# Multiple upload buttons on page: only the first one works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I need to have **several upload buttons on one page**. 
Each upload button would be next to an item, and the user will be able to upload an image for that specific item.

Right now, **only the first upload button** at the top of the page **works** and allows to select a file. The **other ones do not work**: nothing happens when clicked.

```
<div class="upload_icon" >
   <form  action="upload_extra.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input  id="upload"  type="file" name="image"  style="display:none" />   
     <input name="postid" type="hidden" />
     <img id="upload_img" src="/images/uploadicon.png">
   </form>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#upload_img').click(function(){
   $('#upload').click();
   });
</script>
```

What should I do to fix this behavior ?

Comment: why do you want to .click() a file input? that doesn't do anything AFAIK...

Comment: I want to be able to browse/select a file once the icon is clicked.

Comment: then you need to click the input with the mouse or keyboard, a jquery command will not work. in chrome, you can click a <label> pointing to the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID's must be unique; when you have multiple items with the same ID, jQuery will only the select the first one, so your click handler is only being applied to one image. Try using classes instead of ID's.

```
<div class="upload_icon" >
   <form  action="upload_extra.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input  class="upload"  type="file" name="image"  style="display:none" />   
     <input name="postid" type="hidden" />
     <img class="upload_img" src="/images/uploadicon.png">
   </form>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('.upload_img').click(function(){
           $(this).parent().find('.upload').click();
       });
   });
</script>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6uvZu/)**

Comment: It needs to be `$(this).siblings(".upload")` to click on the appropriate element.

Comment: Actually this solution will be a bigger problem! You will click every button,not the one that is in the same form!

Comment: Oops! Posted too quickly and didn't check it... Thanks for the catch, I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work. Actually, now the first button doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6uvZu/... could you post a jsFiddle that shows it not working?

Comment: It now works, i guess i messed up when i copy pasted your code. Thansk a lot !